# Show/Hide based on checkbox checked/unchecked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have 5 checkboxes.  4 of them have to show/hide based on whether the 5th is checked/unchecked.  I'm trying to do this using JQuery, however I'm not quite getting it right for some reason.  I'm hitting the sections of code that check the checked/unchecked property correctly, just not getting the actual show/hide code correct.  I have tried it using a CSS Class for the checkboxes I need to toggle.  Here's the JQuery and .aspx code

```
$(function () {
      $('#<%=chkFrench.ClientID %>').unbind('click');

      $('#<%=chkFrench.ClientID %>').click(function () {

          enable_cb();
          $(".EnhancedFrench").click(enable_cb);
      });
  });

  function enable_cb() {
      if (this.checked) {
          alert("show");
          $('.EnhancedFrench').show();
      } else {
        alert("hide");
          $('.EnhancedFrench').hide();
      }
  }

  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Display Live (Fr):</td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkFrench" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" />/td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>French1</td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>French2</td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox2" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" /></td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
     <td>French3</td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox3" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>French4</td>
     <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox4" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" /></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: you are not passing the object when calling enable_cb()

Comment: @MarkHighfield should that rule apply on each clicked checkbox and hide the rest or only to `CheckBox4` ?

Comment: basically, if chkFrench is checked, the other 4 should be visible, else the other 4 should not be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt check it but it should work

```
$(function () {
  $('#<%=chkFrench.ClientID %>').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
     $('.EnhancedFrench').show();

 }else{
   $('.EnhancedFrench').hide();
 }
  });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick sample. For the code provided you may try using something like below.

This should hide all the checkboxes if last checkbox is checked

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('[id$="chkFrench"]').bind('change', function () { enable_cb(); });
    });

    function enable_cb() {
        if ($('[id$="chkFrench"]').is(':checked')) {
            $('span.EnhancedFrench:gt(0)').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('span.EnhancedFrench:gt(0)').show();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: sorry, I didn't word my question very well. I need the rest to show/hide with chkFrench checkbox is checked/unchecked

Comment: i updated the answer. You may want to change the show and hide method calls as required

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep the checkboxes into a container and use that container to show hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in following way:

```
$('tr:nth-child(5)').find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
    $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').siblings().fadeToggle();
});
```